# How to increment the one column value on click?

Tags: javascript, html

My table row contains 5 columns and each row has `save`, `delete` and `update` buttons in dynamic table.
How to increment one column's value when I click on the `update` button?

1) List item

```
element1 = document.createElement("input")
element1.setAttribute("type", "text");
element1.setAttribute("value", value);
element1.setAttribute('class','');
element1.setAttribute(disableExternalCapture());
tempCell.appendChild(element1);
```

Comment: which is the question? the title or the body?

Comment: give your complete code to analyse the workout

Comment: title when i update a row one of the column in that row will increment.

Comment: Once again - give us html code and js code.
And the best solution would be [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)